# Get unique user identifier of JWT tokens in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, auth0

How can i get a unique user identifier of JWT tokens in Express.js? The user was authenticated previously with Auth0. I need a unique user identifier for creating a CouchDB instance for this user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript), it should be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a unique id given by `Auth0`? You can put it inside the JWT and get it back when validating it.

Comment: From Auth0 i get only a JWT token. I search for a best practise to get a unique identifier in express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the user id of the authenticated user corresponds to the subject claim (sub) of your JWT token. This is probably what you're looking for.